# How to lazy load images without altering img tags or HTML for dynamically (user) generated images

Tags: jquery, html, css, lazy-loading

I know there are plenty of ways to lazy load images, but is there a way to do it ultimately without modifying the `<img>` tags?

The [tool](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) that seems to be the most popular says it cannot be done.

The HTML cannot be changed because it is used as input and cannot be altered unless the user does so.

Appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you have a normal `<img>` tag with a `src` property set, then the browser will start loading the image as the page is parsed.  So, if you want to lazy load, you can't have a normal `<img>` tag with a `src` property set.  Not much more to it than that.  You can show images other ways than with an `<img>` tag (background or canvas, for example) and use JS to render those and not use `<img>` tags at all, but it doesn't appear that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not a way to do that.  If you have `<img>` tags in the HTML with `src` properties specified in them, then the browser will start loading those when the page is parsed.  So they will not be lazy loaded and there is nothing you can do with Javascript to prevent that because the loading of the image will start or be queued up as the page is parsed which is before your Javascript has a chance to run to modify anything.  So, by the time you can try to influence things with your Javascript, the images have already started loading.

Making images invisible with CSS (display: none or visibility: hidden) does not prevent the images from loading so you can't influence things that way.

---

I don't really understand fully what your limitations are, but one way to lazy load is to not have the content containing the lazy load `<img>` tags in the original HTML at all.  Then, you can insert blocks of unmodified HTML with Javascript after the fact when you want them to display.  You would, of course, have to be able to fetch or construct the "blocks of HTML" that you want to insert.

Another possibility (which is more of a stretch) would be to load a "container" page that doesn't have the real content in it, then dynamically fetch the page HTML that you want to display using Ajax, then modify the HTML (to modify the `<img>` tags in the HTML) using your Javascript before inserting the HTML into your container.

Getting even wilder, you could use a proxy server that would make the necessary modifications to the raw HTML to configure lazy loading (modify the `<img>` tags).

Comment: Hmm.. Sounds like you're probably right. I suppose the only way to do this is by not having the content in the DOM in the first place, but rather only placed in there after the DOM loads using JavaScript, which is technically altering the HTML, but actually could work for my specific application.

Comment: @Max - yep, that's one possible solution.

Comment: I am not sure of what going to ask, but what if with javascript we listen to body onload and whenever there's an `img` tag we grab the value of the `src` attributem then leave it empty, push it into an array and leave the `<img src=""` then onready we loop through that array element and inject the elements to the corresponding `img` tag?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity- at the point of the body `onload` event, the document is already fully parsed and all images are already in the process of being loaded.  It's too late at that point to thwart image loading.

Comment: Umm I wasn't sure of that, thanks for this clarification